# LINQ Unir una consulta en una sola fila

Tags: vb.net, linq

Tengo una consulta LINQ a la cual le concateno los valores de una tabla en un solo campo para mostrar en el `DataGridView`

```
Dim Consulta = (From ConsultaConceptos In ds.Tables("Concepto")
                     Select New With { _
                               .Concepto = "Cantidad: " & ConsultaConceptos.Field(Of String)("cantidad") & " ValorUnitario: " & ConsultaConceptos.Field(Of String)("valorUnitario") & " importe:  " & ConsultaConceptos.Field(Of String)("importe") & " Descripción: " & ConsultaConceptos.Field(Of String)("descripcion")
                           })
DataGridView1.DataSource = Consulta.ToList
```

El caso es que en la tabla `Concepto` puede haber más de una fila, a diferencia de las de más tablas que siempre tendran solo 1.

Ejemplo:

```
____________Concepto_______________
dato             dato             dato      dato  fila1
__________________________________
dato             dato             dato      dato  fila2
__________________________________
dato             dato             dato      dato  fila3
```

Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente:

Mostrar las filas 1,2 y 3 en una sola

```
____________Concepto_______________
dato dato dato dato dato dato dato dato dato dato dato dato  fila 1
```

De antemano sé que esto es posible porque ya está hecho en un sistema existente.

Comment: Hola Diego, bienvenido al sitio. ¿Quieres algo similar a una [tabla dinámica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabla_din%C3%A1mica)?

Comment: Hola Luiggi ,basicamente lo que quiero es unir el contenido de N cantidad de filas en una sola

Comment: pista: utiliza join sobre la lista resultante `Consulta.ToList` que ademas te permite utilizar un separador (opcionalmente), quiza te convenga crear la cadena primero y luego el objeto fila.

Comment: ¿Y cómo sería el resultado? Por ejemplo si la tabla `Concepto` tiene 4 columnas: `id`, `nombre`, `cantidad`, `precio` y 2 filas: `1 | Manzana | 1 | 0.50` y `2 | Plátano | 5 | 1.00`, entonces ¿cómo quieres que luzca el resultado? Por favor agrega ejemplos concretos sobre lo que necesitas y así podremos ayudarte más. Por ejemplo no es lo mismo mostrar en una sola fila datos que no se relacionan a mostrar en una sola fila datos sumarizados asociados a un dato superior.

Comment: Tienes razón Luiggi , Mira siguiendo tu ejemplo: 2 filas: 1  Manzana  1  0.50 y 2  Plátano  5  1.00 , el resultado que espero seria el siguiente:
1 fila: 1  Manzana  1  0.50 2  Plátano  5  1.00 , quito los "|" porque ya estan en una sola celda gracias a que mi consulta ya concatena cada celda en una sola llamada Concepto

Comment: @md , sobre utilizar join sobre mi consulta resultante seria algo a si? Dim nuevaConsulta = From ConsultaConcepto In ds.Tables("Concepto") _Join md In Consulta.ToList On ConsultaConcepto.Field(Of Int32)("conceptos_id") _ Equals md.Field(Of Int32)("conceptos_id") Select New With {campos} , solo que no me permite comparar md.Field porque dice que no es miembro de un tipo anonimo

Comment: trate de hacer algo como esto
Dim tabla As New DataTable tabla.Columns.Add("Concepto")
Dim Row As System.Data.DataRow = tabla.NewRow() Row("Concepto") = Consulta.AsEnumerable tabla.Rows.Add(Row)
DataGridView1.DataSource = tabla ,me regresa una sola fila como quiero pero con esto: "System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection`1[VB$AnonymousType_4`1[System.String]]"

Comment: Solucionado por Jose R. MCP

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/es-ES/adcb85c1-d41a-4ac3-9155-addbfaaf8aeb/linq-datagridview-unir-filas-en-una-sola?forum=vbes&prof=required

Saludos y gracias por su tiempo

Answer (score 1):

Tomado de la respuesta que indica @DiegoCantú desde el sitio de MSDN. Esta publicación tiene la intención de contener la respuesta del sitio de MSDN también en este lugar. Si Jose R. MCP tiene un usuario en SOes, favor de comentarle que publique su respuesta para eliminar esta publicación. Se pide encarecidamente **no votar a favor ni en contra** de esta respuesta. Visiten la respuesta original en https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/es-ES/adcb85c1-d41a-4ac3-9155-addbfaaf8aeb/linq-datagridview-unir-filas-en-una-sola?forum=vbes&prof=required

---

> Ok.  Existen los operadores en VB.net?  Podría agregarle un operador implícito de conversión a String a la clase Dato.  Creo que eso eliminaría el uso de () =>, que se llama expresión lambda.
>
> Pero mejor no lo compliquemos.  Hagamos la ruta larga.
>
> ```
> public class Dato
> {
>     //Declaramos una propiedad tipo string para contener el valor.
>     public string Valor { get; set; }
>     public override string ToString() { return Valor; }
> }
>
>
> //Luego hacemos lo que hacíamos pero coleccionamos objetos tipo Dato, no tipo String como antes.
> var filas = from cc in ds.Tables["Concepto"].Rows
>             select new Dato() { Valor = String.Format("Cantidad:  {0} ValorUnitario:  {1} Importe:  {2} Descripción:  {3}",
>             cc["cantidad"], cc["valorUnitario"], cc["importe"], cc["descripcion"]) };
>
> var listaFilas = filas.ToList();
> if (listaFilas.Count > 0)
> {
>     string r = String.Empty;
>     foreach Dato d in listaFilas
>   {
>       r += " " + d.Valor;
>   }
>   r = r.Trim();
>   listaFilas.Clear();
>     Dato d = new Dato()
>     {
>         Valor = r
>     };
>     listaFilas.Add(d);
> }
> DataGridView1.DataSource = listaFilas;
> ```
>
> ¿Mejor?